# I use the generic type and set a nil value, but the result is `nil == nil` is false. How to solve this problem?

Tags: swift, generics, option-type

The code will print value is nil, but `value == nil` is false. How can i do something for it.

```
import Foundation

struct Token: Codable {
    var token: String
    var refreshToken: String
}

class User {

    @Storage(key: "User.Name.Token", defaultValue: Token(token: "testToken", refreshToken: "TestRefreshToken"))
    var token: Token?

    var isLogined: Bool {
        return token != nil
    }

    static let shared = User()
    private init() { }

    func logout() {
        token = nil
    }
}

@propertyWrapper
struct Storage<T: Codable> {
    private let key: String
    private let defaultValue: ()->T

    init(key: String, defaultValue: @escaping @autoclosure ()->T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data,
                  let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else {
                return defaultValue()
            }
            print( "value is \(value)  " +  " but  \(value == nil)")
            return value
        }

        set {
            guard newValue != nil else {
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
                return
            }
            let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

print( "before \(User.shared.token)")
User.shared.logout()
print( "after \(User.shared.token)")
```

Comment: `value` is of type `T` - and it is never optional. So comparing against `nil` will always return `false`.

Comment: After decoding... what exactly do you want your value to be? It looks like you try to handle optionals, yet you set a default value if decoding fails.

Comment: yes, if the value is nil, i want to use the default value. But now it is nil, and don't use the default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your wrapped value to be optional you can change it to:

```
var wrappedValue: T? { // <- make it optional
    get {
        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data,
            let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            return defaultValue()
        }
        // after guard-let the `value` will never be `nil`
        print("value is \(value)")
        return value
    }

    set {
        guard newValue != nil else {
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
            return
        }
        let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

---

Note that here `value` can be `nil` if decoding fails:

```
let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
```

But if you use `guard-let` it will return `defaultValue()` if value is `nil` and never go past the `guard` block:

```
guard let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else {
    return defaultValue()
}
// here `value` can't be `nil`
```

Comment: @Terriermon You need your token to be optional `@Storage(...) var token: Token?`. So you have to make your property wrapper handle optional value (hence added `var wrappedValue: T?`). Why you couldn't do `value == nil` I've already explained above.

Comment: Now the default value can't be nil. But in some case I need it is nil

Comment: @Terriermon If you refer to the `defaultValue` property `private let defaultValue: () -> T` you can make it return an optional: `private let defaultValue: () -> T?`

Comment: @Terriermon I recommend you read more about `guard-let` block: [Guard Statements](https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/). And about optionals as well.